# Maven test not running cucumber tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, cucumber, bdd

In my sample spring boot security project I want to add some BDD tests. I have added dependencies, feature file, sep definition etc. but `mvn test` ignoring all my test classes.
I have some junit and selenium tests which are running fine.

Project is public https://gitlab.com/vivart/spring-boot-security to make it more simple I have removed all junit and selenium test.

Note: I have already tried all similar question suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ahve done 2 modificatuons and able to run test:

**1:**  Scenario keyword is missing in your feature file. Instead you have given Login:

```
Feature: Login
  Scenario: Login functionality
```

**2:** `CucumberTestContextConfiguration` class is missing. Please add it to your `src/test/java` like below:

```
package com.example.auth;

import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CucumberTestContextConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: As I have made some changes in step definition file like url and location and all, I am not checkin into your code. However Able to launch test in my local. Let me know if i need to check in.